# Google App Engine error

Tags: google-app-engine

I get an error while trying an application on Google App Engine as below...any idea why?
My hunch is since I'm behind a proxy, I'm not able to connect to the appengine. If thats the case how do i set it up?

```
Initializing App Engine server
Apr 25, 2012 1:07:32 PM com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory getVersion
INFO: Unable to access http://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java&release=1.5.4&timestamp=1315604504&api_versions=['1.0']
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory.getVersion(RemoteVersionFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.checkForUpdates(UpdateCheck.java:99)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.doNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.maybePrintNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:142)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.maybePerformUpdateCheck(AppEngineLauncher.java:115)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Answer (score 3):

By default the development server checks for updates during startup, you can disable it using [`--disable_update_check`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the appcfg command from [appengine-sdk](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) to pass the proxy. For me it worked.

Example :

```
appcfg --proxy=10.35.71.201:8080 update ../target/exploded_war
```

Answer (score -1):

At the end of https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3131

Solution: create a file with name: `.appcfg_no_nag`

In the user path `System.getProperty("user.home")`, disable the update action.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13177185)

Comment: link-only?  can't you see the solution following the link? @Cyril Duchon-Doris

Comment: I just replaced quotes by backticks, I'm not the downvoter here. Maybe @BenRhys-Lewis

Comment: sorry ~, i made a mistake.@Cyril Duchon-Doris